# Easiest way to transfer a folder through SSH to local?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, directory

Is there a method besides scp that allows me to transfer a folder from an SSH'd network to my local computer? Unfortunately, I don't have the password, or I would have done so myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FISH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol) to use SSH to transfer files without using scp.

Answer (score 0):

When I don't feel like using SCP I usually use `mail`.

```
mail user@domain.com -a yourfile.txt
```

You could use `mutt` instead of `mail` if you like (or some other mail client). If you use the command above, it will prompt you for a subject and a message body in a vi editor. If you're not familiar, just type :wq to quit out of it. Then press 'y' to send the email.

if you do something like

```
echo "whatever" | mutt -a myfile -s "subject"
```

then it doesn't prompt you to type in more stuff.